# SQL Query row needs to decrement from group total until value is zero or new group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables:

Order Detail Table

```
| OrderId | OrderDetailId | ItemId | QtyOrdered | DateNeeded |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 16669   | 36915         | 139    | 10         | 2019-10-21 |
| 16669   | 36916         | 139    | 15         | 2019-11-21 |
| 16670   | 36917         | 11     | 1          | 2019-10-21 |
| 16673   | 36922         | 250    | 5          | 2019-10-11 |
| 16673   | 36923         | 139    | 10         | 2019-10-11 |
```

and an Order Allocation Table

```
| OrderId | ItemId | ItemLot | QtyAllocated |
---------------------------------------------
| 16669   | 139    | 2345678 | 2            |
| 16669   | 139    | 2256245 | 3            |
| 16669   | 139    | 2356245 | 10           |
| 16673   | 139    | 2356245 | 8            |
| 16673   | 139    | 2245689 | 2            |
| 16673   | 250    | 2019001 | 5            |
```

Here is the scenario:  Order 16669 has two lines on it, but for the same Item and different quantities with different delivery dates.  Order 16670 has one line and 16673 has two lines with different Items.  I need to be able to report out Order detail with corresponding allocated or backordered quantities.

You can see from the second table that Order 16669 has a total of 15 units allocated for ItemId 139.  I need to report this as 10 units allocated to OrderDetailId 36915 (we want to show this line as fully allocated since the date needed is sooner that OrderDetailId 36916).  There is no direct link between the allocation table and Order Detail only via the OrderId.

Here is an example of what I need to build with a query, but haven't been able to figure out:

```
| OrderId | DetailId | ItemId | OrderQty | TotalAlloc | AllocQty | BackorderQty|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16669   | 36915    | 139    | 10       | 15         | 10       | 0           |
| 16669   | 36916    | 139    | 15       | 15         | 5        | 10          |
| 16670   | 36917    | 11     | 1        | 0          | 0        | 1           |
| 16673   | 36922    | 250    | 5        | 5          | 5        | 0           |
| 16673   | 36923    | 139    | 10       | 10         | 10       | 0           |
```

For order 16669 a total of 15 units have been allocated.  Row #1 requires 10 of those units leaving 5 units for the next line(s) and a 0 qty backorder.  Row 2 requires 15 units so we take the remaining 5 units and show a backorder quantity of 10.  Row 3 begins a new Order (or could be same order but different Item) so we reset.

I'm pretty sure the answer is some variation of a SUM OVER query, but haven't been able to get there.

Could anyone help me find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the answer is some variation of a SUM OVER query.

You are right.You can play with  `Rows-Range thing` to get there.

Try this script ,

```
CREATE TABLE #Order(OrderId int,OrderDetailId int, ItemId int, QtyOrdered int,  DateNeeded date)
insert into #Order values
 (16669  , 36915, 139, 10 ,'2019-10-21'),(16669  , 36916, 139, 15 ,'2019-11-21')
,(16670  , 36917, 11 , 1  ,'2019-10-21'),(16673  , 36922, 250, 5  ,'2019-10-11')
,(16673  , 36923, 139, 10 ,'2019-10-11')


CREATE TABLE #OrderAllocation (OrderId int, ItemId int, ItemLot bigint,  QtyAllocated int)
insert into #OrderAllocation values
 (16669,139,2345678, 2 ),(16669, 139,2256245,3)
,(16669,139,2356245, 10),(16673, 139,2356245,8)
,(16673,139,2245689, 2),(16673, 250,2019001,5);

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT OrderId,
                ItemId,
                SUM(QtyAllocated) TotalAlloc
         FROM #OrderAllocation
         GROUP BY OrderId,
                  ItemId),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT o.OrderId,
                o.OrderDetailId AS DetailId,
                o.ItemId,
                o.QtyOrdered AS OrderQty,
                ISNULL(TotalAlloc, 0) TotalAlloc,
                SUM(QtyOrdered) OVER(PARTITION BY o.OrderId,
                                                  o.ItemId
                ORDER BY o.dateneeded ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) RunningAllocQty,
                DateNeeded
         FROM #Order O
              LEFT JOIN CTE C ON o.OrderId = c.orderid
                                 AND o.ItemId = c.ItemId)
     SELECT OrderId,
            DetailId,
            ItemId,
            OrderQty,
            TotalAlloc,
            CASE
                WHEN TotalAlloc > 0
                THEN OrderQty - ISNULL(RunningAllocQty, 0)
                ELSE 0
            END AllocQty,
            CASE
                WHEN TotalAlloc > 0
                THEN OrderQty - (OrderQty - ISNULL(RunningAllocQty, 0))
                ELSE OrderQty
            END BackOrderQty
     FROM CTE1;

drop table #Order,#OrderAllocation
```

In this script, you can fix `join condition`, if it is wrong.

Query can be optimized after getting familiar with data. 
In this small sample data, there are so many doubts.